# How to make reverse video and editing in video file in android programmatically?

Tags: android, video

I want to make an application like video editor which can reverse the video and also we can change the mode the video like , if video in colorful then we could black and white with the help of editor functionality.

I have seen many application in play store but i could not see any example of reverse video programmatically in android.

how can i develop these functionalities in android?

Thank You

Comment: use to ffmpeg that for, and that kind of demo you can't get

Comment: @Ravi :- i get only one of the answer that use "FFMPEG" but how can i use in android ? how can i integrate "FFMPEG"? what is the steps behinde that? i did not get answers last 6 month..and even not get any example in google of FFMPEG..

Comment: yes bro, i have also try this but not go success

Comment: what you think about to do ?

Comment: @Ravi still searching.. what else can..what about you?

Comment: Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33230307/reverse-video-in-android/44605003#44605003) for reversing video in android