# ffmpeg - convert image sequence to video with reversed order

Tags: ffmpeg

Looking at [the docs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images), it is not apparent to me whether ffmpeg would allow me to convert an image sequence to a video in reverse order, for example using this sequence:

```
frame-1000.jpg
frame-999.jpg
frame-998.jpg
...
frame-1.jpg
```

Is it possible to give a "step direction" for the frame indices?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Due to happenstance of your naming scheme, you're in luck.

FFmpeg's image sequence demuxer has a start number option and I've confirmed that it accepts negative values.

So,

```
ffmpeg -start_number -1000 -i frame%d.jpg reversed.mp4
```

Here the '-' has to be interpreted as part of the number series, so it's `frame%d` and not `frame-%d`.

Comment: I'm looking for this terribly, but this is not working with my Entangled files: capture000447.jpg to capture000000.jpg :(

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: If your frames have the format `frame0001.jpg, frame0002.jpg, ...` and you have ubuntu, you can simple rename the files in a batch by replacing `frame` with `frame-`.

Answer (score 9):

There is a reverse video filter, so something like

`ffmpeg -i frame-%d.jpg -vf reverse reversed.mp4`

would work also.

Comment: Be aware that the reverse filter buffers the entire decoded image sequence in memory.

Comment: This results in corrupted video file for me.

Comment: Seems to work well, at least for short videos