# FFMPEG images sequence normal and reverse to single video

Tags: ffmpeg, jpeg

I have a bunch of images

- img01.jpg
- img02.jpg
- img03.jpg .... (up to img_45.jpg)

I would like to produce a video that will play the images in such way

- img01.jpg
- img02.jpg
- img03.jpg
- img02.jpg
- img01.jpg

Possible?

Comment: You could always do it in reverse and concat the results.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/40475480/362536

Comment: Thanks but what if I had to run multiple batch where some have 100 images and some have 50? Basically is there a way to reverse when the last image file has reached? If I’m not mistaken, that solution requires to define the last image number.

Comment: Defining the last image number should be trivial with shell scripting, but I can't give an example because I'm not sure what OS you're using.

Comment: Thanks! Windows command line

Comment: @GuyAzouri Didn't get notified of your response. If you mention my user name like I did with yours it will notify. (Un)fortunately I don't use Windows so I can't help with that part, but I can provide an answer for the ffmpeg part of your question if that is acceptable. Then you can make a new, separate question about how to implement it into a batch-file or powershell script for automation.

Comment: Still waiting for that solution...