# Concat a video with itself, but in reverse, using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, reverse

I was able to reverse with:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf reverse output_reversed.mp4
```

And I can concat with:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:0] [0:1] [1:0] [1:1] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

But can I concat with a reverse version of the video, with a single command?

What I am trying to achieve is a ping pong effect, where the video plays once, then plays backwards right after.

Thanks!

Comment: a.k.a. "yo-yo" or "slingshot"

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Technically, you can do it using

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]reverse,fifo[r];[0:v][0:a][r] [0:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

But the reverse filter will use a lot of memory for large videos. I've added a `fifo` filter to avoid frame drops. But test and see. (I haven't reversed the audio)

If your clip has no audio, the above command will throw an error – instead, use:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]reverse,fifo[r];[0:v][r] concat=n=2:v=1 [v]" -map "[v]" output.mp4
```

Comment: That's perfect, thanks!
It will be used for very short videos, with no audio, so that's pretty much all I needed.

Comment: If you're using this on something with no audio stream (I wanted to run this on a gif) you'll get an error, but this works instead:

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]reverse,fifo[r];[0:v][r] concat=n=2:v=1 [v]" -map "[v]" output.mp4`

Comment: @tobek is it possible to let ffmpeg repeat the operation 2 or more times? To get the video looped back and forth a few times.

Comment: @SharpAffair probably, but I'm a bit of a hack with ffmpeg and I don't know how to do it. I needed the same, and just repeated the command a few times (changing input and output obviously). You could script this if you needed to do it a bunch, or maybe ask a new question about it.

Comment: Added @tobek's non-audio solution to the answer above

Comment: Tried to do this on a 200mb video file. It ate all of my 16gb of ram and then froze my computer. Just to add an example of  what "a lot of memory" means