# Matplotlib reverse animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

When using `animation.FuncAnimation`, is it possible to optimally reverse an animation after it plays in forward? i.e. equivalent of

```py
FuncAnimation(.., frames=np.hstack([range(10), range(9)[::-1]]))
```

This redraws frames in reverse order, eating up drawing computation and memory when 50% of data is exactly the same. `FuncAnimation` does have a caching mechanism, but does it or any other `animation.` have a `reverse=True`? Note all my data is pre-computed and retrieved via simple index for each frame.

Comment: If it is precomputed, why don't you use [ArtistAnimation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/animation/dynamic_image.html#sphx-glr-gallery-animation-dynamic-image-py)? That is exactly the kind of application this flip book approach is designed for.

Comment: I agree with Mr T.   I used artist and `framelist += framelist[-1::-1]` and it works like a charm!!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a solution within the (interactive?) matplotlib backend or are you writing this animation to file?

The latter is quite a lot simpler, as you could simply use a tool like `ffmpeg` to revert&append the final gif/movie file. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42257863/565489), for example.

If you need a solution *within* matplotlib then I guess you'd need to store all your required calculations in separate objects (e.g. create a dictionary like `frames = { 0: {"x":0, "y":1, … } }` and then tell the FuncAnimation to update with a simple "lookup" function like:

```
def update(frame):
    xdata = frames[frame]["x"]
    ydata = frames[frame]["y"]
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return ln,
```

A third option would be to store your axes as pickle'd object, i.e.:

```
pickle.dump(ax, file('frame_0.pickle', 'w'))
```

and then try to re-load those pickle'd frames within FuncAnimation's update call like:

```
ax = pickle.load(file('frame_0.pickle'))
```