# FFmpeg how to reverse gif in shall scrip

Tags: shell, ffmpeg, gif

I'm new to shell scripting,
I'm using the following shell script to convert mp4 into gif:

```
palette="/tmp/palette.png"
filters="fps=12,scale=256:-1:flags=lanczos"
ffmpeg -v warning -i $1 -vf "$filters,palettegen" -y $palette
ffmpeg -v warning -i $1 -i $palette -lavfi "$filters [x]; [x][1:v] paletteuse" -y $2
```

how do I use the [reverse option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42257354/concat-a-video-with-itself-but-in-reverse-using-ffmpeg) (like this sample here) in the **filter** section in this **shell script**:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]scale=320:-1,reverse[r];[0][r]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0,fps=10,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" output.gif
```

Answer (score 1):

One line:

```
ffmpeg -i "$1" -filter_complex "[0]fps=12,scale=256:-1:flags=lanczos,split[main][reverse];[reverse]reverse[r];[main][r]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" "$2"
```

Usage example: `./gifinator input.mp4 output.gif`

Don't forget to give proper permission to execute the script: `chmod +x gifinator`